# Overriding a low level node.js module

Tags: node.js, ssl, amazon-s3

Amazon S3 allows static website hosting, but with a requirement that the bucket name must match your domain name.  This means your bucket name will look like: mydomain.com.  Amazon S3 also provides a wildcard SSL certificate for *.s3.amazonaws.com. By the rules of TLS, this means com.s3.amazonaws.com IS covered by the certificate, but mybucket.com.s3.amazonaws.com is not. Node applications, like [Knox](https://github.com/LearnBoost/knox) that connect to *.com.s3.amazonaws.com should really be able to trust that certificate, even though it breaks the rules of TLS, since the knox library is a 'closed system': it only ever connects to an Amazon property.

The Node module `https` relies on `tls.js`, and `tls.js` has this function:

```
function checkServerIdentity(host, cert) {
...
// "The client SHOULD NOT attempt to match a presented identifier in
// which the wildcard character comprises a label other than the
// left-most label (e.g., do not match bar.*.example.net)."
// RFC6125
if (!wildcards && /*/.test(host) || /[.*].**/.test(host) ||
    /*/.test(host) && !/*.*..+..+/.test(host)) {
   return /$./;
 }
```

Which will properly return a "Certificate Mismatch" error.  Can the upper level Knox module override the checkServerIdentity function, which is several levels down and not called directly by Knox? I know how to override a function in a library I require, but not libraries that are included by these libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a global cache for modules, which means that any function you override will be modified for all other modules. I think you can include `tls` yourself and patch `checkServerIdentity`:

```
// main.js
var tls = require('tls'),
    mod = require('./mod.js');

tls.checkServerIdentity = function (host, cert) {
  return true;
};

mod.test();
```

```
// mod.js
var tls = require('tls');

exports.test = function () {
  console.log(tls.checkServerIdentity()); // true
};
```

Comment: Asking for clarification: do you mean to say that by my including tls in my app, and overriding the function, will also override it in the global cache, or are you saying by doing it via your pseudo code does NOT modify the global cache?

Comment: Yes: overriding the function will override it in the global cache. My example shows that changing tls in main.js also changes it in mod.js

Comment: Thanks, but the override would open up security issues for other node apps if the global cache had my Amazon specific override in it.

Comment: This doesn't change the version of checkServerIdentity that `tls.connect` uses, since it references a local function name, not the variable that is exported.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to make changes to the global module objects (per your comment on Nik's answer), maybe you could use the [rewire](https://github.com/jhnns/rewire) module. I imagine doing it something like this:

```
  var knoxModule = rewire("./node_modules/knox/somefile.js");
  knoxModule.__set__("tls", {
      checkServerIdentity: function (host, cert) {
          // some code
      }
  });
```

I haven't ever worked with it though.